# Asset Library not working on Site Pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, video, asset-library

I have a site page on SharePoint Online.  I've added an Asset Library to it and uploaded a video.  The video's content type has been tagged as Image and I can't play it.  It simply gives me the ability to download it.

How do I change the content type on this video?  Does SharePoint support MOV files?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To the first part:
SharePoint supports MOV-files just fine. You can upload them and you can download them.
However, since there is no `MIME`-mapping they will only be availabe to download and not play in the browser..

To the second part:
There is currently no way to change the `MIME`-mappings in SharePoint-Online.

Go to [vote on UserVioce](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/282887-sharepoint-hybrid-or-migration-to-office365/suggestions/15287109-add-custom-mime-type), maybe it will be implemented some day..

Comment: Nils... thanks for that.  I actually have had a breakthough.  It seems Site Pages (publishing pages) don't know what to do with Videos.  However if you use a web part page, the video is automatically tagged with that content type, you can add a thumbnail on upload, and the video plays directly in the browser w/o the need to download it.  Thanks again.